# Query messages theard list

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I have to show messages thread of login users. Well Showing thread is not actually issue. I im facing trouble while showing all messages list. Requirement is as follow.

1) Messages List page (message_list.php): Only last message will display here that was being send or receive by login user. in that case login users can be sender or receiver. e.g

user "mahendra" is a login users. and had communication with many other users lets say John, Smith, Sandra. On message_list.php page only last message should be displayed within each user.

DB Structure is as follow:

id(pk),from_id,to_id,message

What should be a query for this ?

Comment: you should also add the date field in the table. like send_time etc.

Comment: yes it is there 'date_entered', but is it required for this requirement ?

Comment: yes, it is required. as you want the last message only b/w each user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id for your current user is lets say 5

```
SELECT message FROM yourTable WHERE to_id=5 OR from_id=5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: LIMIT 1 is a problem here. consider situation where login users had communication with more than 1 user. This query will show last records among all communication with other user.

Comment: But you yourself asked for it here `Only last message will display here that was being send or receive by login user`

Comment: I think I could explain properly what exactly I need to show. Okay here it is again.

lets say Login user "mahendra" and John and 5 messages. mahendra and smith has 3 messages. so list should be like following

1) mahendra-john  -  Last Message goes here
2) mahendra-smith -  Last Message goes here